# Complete list of hardware keyboard shortcuts for Desire Z?

Tags: htc-desire-z, keyboard-shortcuts

I like to use the hardware keyboard of the Desire Z including shortcuts, however I haven't found a complete list. For example, the HTC help pages don't mention Function + Backspace = Deletion of text left to the cursor.

Can anyone provide a complete list or further "secret" shortcuts? This might also involve the usage of the optical "trackball", e.g. selecting text by using it while pressing Shift.

Comment: http://www.htc.com/www/howto.aspx?id=18599&type=1&p_id=325 has some info.

Also see - http://www.htc.com/ca/support/desirez-bell/help/tips-and-tricks

Comment: Thanks, these were the help pages I referred to... hope there is more to come!

Comment: In apps where there are shortcuts. Press menu once, then hold menu. The titles of each option should now show their keyboard shortcuts, if available.

Answer (score 1):

As the links in the comments are partly broken, I try to sum some things up here -- before the remaining links go to Nirvana as well.

## Global Shortcuts

```
Access number pad – Tap the 12# button on the keyboard 
Turn on CAPS – Tap and hold the up arrow/Shift key until it has an underline.
Access keyboard settings – Tap the Gear icon on the keyboard
```

## Browser Shortcuts

```
Homepage – Menu + Spacebar
Find – Menu + F
Select text – Menu + E
Page Info – Menu + G
Share Page – Menu + S
Downloads – Menu + D
History – Menu + H
Settings – Menu + P
```

## Messaging Shortcuts

```
Press C to compose new message
Press R to reply
Press A to reply all
Press F to forward
```

(Source: [HTC.COM](http://www.htc.com/ca/support/desirez-bell/help/tips-and-tricks))

## Assigning your own Shortcuts

While on the Home screen, you can quickly open an app or an item by pressing a keyboard shortcut.

1. While on the Home screen, open the slideout keyboard.
2. Press and hold any of the keyboard keys (A ~ Z).
3. Tap OK.
4. Tap Apps or Shortcuts, and then tap the app or shortcut that you want to assign to the selected key. If you are assigning a shortcut to an item on your phone, follow the screen instructions to proceed.
5. While on the Home screen, press and hold the key you’ve assigned a keyboard shortcut to. The app or item opens.

(Source: [HTC.COM](http://www.htc.com/www/help/htc-desire-z/))